# Blog engines for ASP.Net (maybe MVC) web sites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, integration, blogs, blog-engine

I've built a web site on ASP.NET MVC and one little section of it should be a blog. I'm looking for a blog to integrate. In the worst case scenario it'd be a WordPress with a custom skin and RSS integration to the rest of the site. The best would be to have an ASP.NET MVC add-on, but I can live with ASP.NET WebForms.

Do you have any recomendations on the engine? I've been checking out BlogEngine.Net and I'd like to have some other ideas to compare. Anything in particular you can point to regarding this integration?

Comment: By just ASP.NET, I think you mean "ASP.NET WebForms".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, I ended up using WordPress. Applying the "skin" was not hard, probably as hard as with any .Net blog and although it will probably be harder to maintain in the long run, in the short term is probably the most stable and featureful blogging solution.

Comment: As much as I like .NET over PHP there is just nothing on the .NET side that compares with Wordpress.  I'd say you made a good choice.

Comment: Do you have a link to your site? I am planning on building a MVC site but need a blog and thinking I might have to create a skin in Wordpress/PHP instead.

Comment: Jon, sure: http://hearablog.com and http://blog.hearablog.com

Answer (score 8):

Three most famous are those:

Classical Asp.Net

- [dasBlog](https://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/dasblog.aspx) -Edit: updated link (old link pointed at dasblog.info - obviously no longer the correct link)
- [Subtext](http://www.subtextproject.com/)

Asp.Net Mvc

- [Oxite](http://www.codeplex.com/oxite)

Comment: Although we ended up going with a WordPress blog (for non-technical reasons) I was impressed with dasBlog when I took a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

Check [BlogEngine.NET](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/), it is easy to understand and extensible.
It is build using ASP.NET Webforms.

Answer (score 2):

[Scott Hanselman](http://hanselman.com/blog) contributed to [DasBlog](http://www.dasblog.info/) and is using it as his blog engine - it was created with hosting in mind, so works under medium trust and doesn't use a DB.

It is an WebForms app, not MVC, however. He runs his blog with it.

Comment: Scott Hanselman did not create DasBlog.  He did become a committer after it was around for a while.

Comment: @Michael Maddox - I didn't know that. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently been playing with [N2CMS](http://www.n2cms.com/) - it's more of a CMS than just a Blog Engine (which is the main reason I've been playing with it), so might be overkill for your requirements.

It has both Medium Trust support, and an MVC example - I've basically taken the Medium Trust sample and mixed that with the ASP.NET MVC example to produce something that the client's very happy with.

Answer (score 0):

[atomsite](http://atomsite.net/) - not mature enough, but promising