# Integrate "Blog" module into asp.net mvc app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blogs

Is there any open source blog engine code available on asp.net mvc written in c# language? I need to write a blog module for our application. I was wondering if any open source code available means i can use that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084543/blog-engines-for-asp-net-maybe-mvc-web-sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [Oxite](http://www.codeplex.com/oxite)